# how to fix not upating version in liferay?

Tags: liferay

i am using liferay framwork, some message showing  "Not updating Demo *** because version 6.2.5 is newer than version 6.2.0.1" when try do deploy.plz help me.how to fix and update version?

Comment: don't know anything about liferay, but seems like you have a demo Version, which will not update to a newer version, because it's only supposed to be a DEMO

Comment: Can you elaborate on your scenario.. what are you exactly doing.. Are you trying to deploy a plugin to liferay ? What is your liferay version... ?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and add a lot of information: "try to deploy *what*", "how to fix and update version *of what*" - a plugin? Liferay? Provide a log file excerpt rather than just a single message taken out of context. Are you talking about a custom plugin or some Liferay stock- or marketplace plugin? Or no plugin at all? If it's your own: How do you build it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add this line: `module-version=6.2.0.5` under `module-incremental-version=1` in `liferay-plugin-package.properties` file. And it will work. That thing bothered me for a long time too, so I looked into the source code and now it works like a charm. You can experiment with `module-version` number. Example `liferay-plugin-package.properties`:

```
name=Demo
module-group-id=liferay
module-incremental-version=1
module-version=6.2.0.5
tags=
short-description=
long-description=
change-log=
page-url=http://www.liferay.com
author=Liferay, Inc.
licenses=LGPL
liferay-versions=6.2.0+
portal-dependency-jars=\
    groovy.jar,\
    asm.jar,\
    antlr3-runtime.jar,\
    antlr2.jar,\
    antlr3.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

**My guess:**

If you are getting this error while deploying a plugin to liferay server, check in your liferay-plugin-package.properties if there is a liferay version specified which is required by the portlet.
Update the version and if you are still getting the error, remove the portlet from webapps and redeploy again.